# Pandas Dataframe: substract and divided two rows value based on column condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have DataFrame:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.4 | 0.7 | 0.2 |
| 3 | 0 | 4.25 | 100 |
| 3 | -2.5 | 4.20 | 70 |
| 3 | -2.5 | 3.5 | 80 |
| 4 | 0 | 3.6 | 81 |
| 4 | -5 | 3.5 | 77 |
| 4 | -5 | 3.4 | 75 |
| 4 | -5 | 3.1 | 74 |
| 5 | 0 | 3.2 | 75 |
| 5 | 0.1 | 3.3 | 73 |

Now , i want to skip first two rows. after that i want to substarct last row value and first row value for number '3' with coumn 'C' value then divide with same substactction but with coumn 'B' Value. basically, |3.5-4.25|/|-2.5-0| = | 0.3 |

i tried and skiped first two rows with

```
cols = ['A']
df[cols] = df[df[cols] > 2][cols]
df = df.dropna()
```

Expected output:

| NEW_COL | Result |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 |
| 2 | 0.1 |
| 3 | 1 |

could you please help me?

Comment: can you correct the 0.04 to 0.1 if this was a mistake? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can compute the last-first per group, then divide C/B and drop NAs:

```
out = (df.groupby('A')
         .agg(lambda g: abs(g.iloc[-1]-g.iloc[0]))
         .eval('C/B')
         .dropna()
         .reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

output:

```
0    0.3
1    0.1
2    1.0
dtype: float64
```